# How to make vuetify tooltip content cliquable?

Tags: vue.js, tooltip, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have vuetify tooltip tht contains a button.

The problem is that the tooltip disappears before I can click on the button.

How can I make the content of the tooltip cliquable.

[image]

Comment: you can add a `close-delay`, but is the menu component not a better choice for this kind of interaction?

Comment: [click-on-tooltip-content-vuetify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549488/click-on-tooltip-content-vuetify)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `close-delay` prop to make the tooltip stay open for a longer time but I assume that it's contents still won't be clickable because of some `z-index` issue.

for a clickable content on hover you can use `v-menu` like this:

[menu on hover](https://codepen.io/Hamid-Niakan/pen/PoGpYmd?editors=101)